# How to take input in 2d array from scanf when input is given in single row?

Tags: c, 2d, scanf

```
  char dic[2][2];
  //Storing it
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while (i < 2) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < 2) {
      scanf("%c", &dic[i][j++]);
    }
    i++;
  }

  //Printing it
  i = 0;
  while (i < 2) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < 2) {
      printf("%c", dic[i][j++]);
    }
    i++;
  }
```

Input is Given in single like

```
A B C D.
```

When I am trying to print it it is printing A B only.

Can someone suggest me what I am missing?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You haven’t shown how you print the data out nor do you initialize i anywhere etc.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: `scanf("%c", . . .)` reads *every* character input. try adding a space before `%c` like `scanf(" %c", &dic[i][j++]);` which then ignores leading whitespace.